# Android strings generated by Gradle's flavors declared missing translations by lint

Tags: android, gradle, lint

In Android studio I have a build.gradle file that has 2 flavors. These two flavors have a string whose value changes depending on the flavor. For example ...

```
productFlavors {
    companyOne {
        resValue "string", "sharedUserId", "com.company1"
    }

    companyTwo {
        resValue "string", "sharedUserId", "com.company2"
    }
}
```

Gradle generates this string for each flavor. The problem is that when lint gets run it complains that this id is a "MissingTranslation". I want to run lint and find any missing translations for all my other strings, so I don't want to turn it off. I just don't want this string inspected. The problem basically is that the string that is generated looks like this

```
 <string name="sharedUserId">com.company1</string>
```

what I really want is a string that is generated to look like this ...

```
 <string name="sharedUserId" translatable="false">com.company1</string>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I found a Google issue tracker for this, that says its fixed. But its not!! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37024130